# Where does the JET Driver for accessing Excel spreadsheets using ADO.NET come from?

Tags: excel, ado.net

I am trying to avoid needing Excel on a Server and so am considering using a JET driver and ADO.NET.

My question is, how is the Jet driver normally obtained or is it normally part of the base OS?

We're using Windows 2003 Server .

thx

Comment: It's part of most Windows OS's and some other Apps. The Wikipedia page lists the JET version bundled with various applications. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine. Although JET I thought was dying a slow death...

Comment: Good info. thx. Do you know what is the preferred way to read an Excel 2003 spreadsheet on 2003 Server OS? I'm a little confused about my XML options and afraid that if there is an API for reading Excel XML, it may have changed for 2007. Most of what I see about Excel and XML seems to be for 2007 and greater, so I am confused whether I should be looking into processing Excel 2003 saved as XML.

Comment: Mostly convert to CSV/XML and avoid Excel altogether :). It really depends on how well structured the Excel data is laid out - eg any blank rows and mixed data types tend to make JET a very frustrating experience unless you have access to registry settings. I can see why JET is a consideration now based on 2003. It's all in the Excel data layout though I'm afraid....

Comment: @ChadD If you're unable to use the Microsoft Excel Driver as detailed at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel because the driver is not installed then you can aquire it at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255. There are drivers for both ODBC and OLEDB connections.